# Getting number of arguments accepted by class constructor

Tags: haxe

Given class Foo

```
class Foo
{
    public function new(foo:Int, bar:Int, foobar:Int) {}
}
```

Retrieve number of arguments accepted by `new`. I've tried using `@:rtti` - then I tried

```
for(field in haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(Foo).fields) {
    if (field.name == "new") {
         trace(field.type);
    }
}
```

The result was promising

**

```
TestAll.hx:246: CFunction({
        length : 3,
        h : {
            item : {
                name : foo, 
                opt : false, 
                t : CAbstract(<...>,<...>), 
                value : null
            }, 
            next : {
                item : {
                    name : <...>, 
                    opt : <...>, 
                    t : <...>, 
                    value : null
                }, 
                next : {
                    item : <...>, 
                    next : null
                }
            }
        }, 
        q : {
            item : {
                name : foobar, 
                opt : false, 
                t : CAbstract(<...>,<...>), 
                value : null
            }, 
            next : null
        }
    },CAbstract(Void,{
            length : 0
        }))**
```

So I tried `field.type.length`.

> test/TestAll.hx:246: characters 14-31 : haxe.rtti.CType has no field
>   length

After a quick glance at http://api.haxe.org/haxe/rtti/CType.html#CFunction , 
I can see

```
CFunction(args:List<FunctionArgument>, ret:CType)
```

??? I'm baffled - it contains a List, yet it only returns CType? How to get to the information I want?

Thank you.

PS. I don't want macro solution, this is used inside unit test, and the generation of the construction itself is already macro heavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CType is an enum, and CFunction is one of the possible enum values (or "enum constructors").

You can see the source code here: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/rtti/CType.hx#L42-L51

You'll need to use a `switch` statement to dive into it and get your list:

```
switch (field.type) {
    case CFunction(args,returnType):
        trace(args.length);
    default:
        // Do nothing
}
```

To learn more I recommend these manual pages:

- [Enums](http://haxe.org/manual/types-enum-instance.html)
- [Pattern matching (switch statements)](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-introduction.html)